# Defined names changing reference of formula. Unable to set the Formula property of the picture class

Tags: excel, vba

I have a strange problem. I have a formula to choose between graphics that I put in a picture.
It is `=choose(Dashboard!B2;A;B...)` and so on.
For some reason, it changes the `b2` to `l2c2` and I have no idea how to correct this problem or what caused it in the first place.

EDIT:
Okay, I'll explain it better:
The language is portuguese, but I prefer to come here.

So, I have a sheet where I can select, through a dropdown and buttons, what area I want to view certain charts.

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2mHC.png)

(Hopefully you get the picture through this picture :))
To make this work, I put a serious of Defined Names (Ranges?) and put some =CHOOSE() with all these defined names.

[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wq9D.png)

[Picture 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngfcV.png)

And It was working, until recently. I don't know what changed, don't know what went wrong, but when I click in the buttons, it keeps giving the following alert:

[Picture 4: alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/or1dw.png)
Run-time error '1004': Unable to set the Formula property of the picture class.

And while debugging the code, if I check the defined names, it shows this:

[Picture 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bN6T.png)

Comment: You're not really giving a lot to go on, but by the looks of it you mean `R2C2` rather than `L2C2`?  Go to `File~Options` and select the `Formula` tab.  Is `R1C1 reference style` ticked?  If it's not that then can you give more info please - is it just a `VBA` tag?

Comment: When I get home I'll try to explain better, please wait a little.

Comment: Just thought... might be `L2C2` if it's not English. Solution will be the same though.

Comment: Hi! I edited and tried to explain it better. Please have a look.

Comment: `L2C2` is looking at row 2, column 2 - or `B2`.  Find the `Options` menu (in 2010 it's under `File`) and follow my first comment.  I guess it will be labelled _L1C1 estilo de referência_ in Portuguese.

Comment: Unfortunately, it wasn't ticked. I actually ticked and tried to run it with no sucess, then unticked it again, no sucess.